# How to disable close event of electron in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I have a function in my component.ts

```
isOperationComplete()
{
   return this.Status == "COMPLETE";
}
```

In component I have decorated a function with hostlistener which returns $event.returnValue as true when operation is not complete,

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  unloadNotification($event: any) {

      else if (!this.isOperationComplete()) 
        $event.returnValue =true;

  }
```

in main.js, on close event I am showing a message box in electron window as below,

```
win.on('close', function (e) {
        var choice = dialog.showMessageBox(this,{
            type: 'question',
            buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
            title: 'Confirm',
            message: 'You are attempting to close Application, Do you want to exit?'
        });
        if(choice == 1){
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    })
```

also when user clicks close button of electron, the above message box appears, when user clicks Yes button, if unloadNotification() in component returns true below message box appears.

```
win.webContents.on('will-prevent-unload', (event) => {
      const choice = dialog.showMessageBox(win, {
        type: 'warning',
        buttons:['OK'],
        title: 'Warning',
        message: 'A Critical operation is in progress, Application closing is prevented.'
      })
    })
```

What I want to achieve : When close button of electron UI is clicked, if unloadNotification returns true, I want to show second message box directly, rather than showing to close with Yes & No buttons.